# Dialog pop up box disappears when I try to move my mouse into it

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I hover over, say a css color or line with git commit, a modal / dialog pops up (with the color picker or git info) but when I move my mouse from the line which triggered the pop up (on hover) to the pop up itself (to change the color or  the modal window disappears?

Comment: Found solution - setting (or sticky hover) was set to true in defaults but was being ignored (???). Once  I added it to user settings problem fixed!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73938349/836330 - the hover behaviour should be improved in v1.72 (unrelated to the sticky hover setting).