# VS Code's documentation/intellisense popup disappears on mouse over

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having a problem scrolling through the pop up box after hovering over a variable. It just disappears. I want to be able to scroll through it.

I am on Windows 10 x64 using Visual Studio Code 1.41.1 with Python Extension

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Set `editor.hover.sticky` to `true`.

**Via settings.json**:

```
"editor.hover.sticky": true
```

**Via Settings UI**:

[image]

Comment: I have this option enabled, but the problem remains. I did not have this problem before, so it must be some regression ...

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112373 https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/113406

Comment: @HappyFace I think the issue you linked is related more to scrolling on the popup, while this setting is more about keeping the popup displayed when you mouse over it (before you even start scrolling). I can rep the disappears when scroll-to-bottom issue, but the setting still works AFAICT to make sure the popup stays visible when you mouse over it.

Comment: Try to move your cursor slowly at it otherwise you scare it, it does work.

Answer (score 4):

As a result of [Keep hover visible when the mouse is getting closer to it](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/a02a660b1a286ee2f997a3e25e4b7c5551e3b99d), in my testing in the Insiders Build v1.72 this is much better.  It should be in Stable v1.72 early October, 2022.

From the [1.72 Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_72.md#improved-hover)

> #### Improved hover
>
> The editor hover used to be quite aggressive in hiding itself,
> especially when the mouse was going over an empty area of the editor.
> This would make it very difficult to reach some of the actions shown
> in the hover. Now, the hover will stay visible as long as the mouse is
> moving towards it. The setting `"editor.hover.sticky": false` will
> continue to work as before:

---

[The `Editor > Hover: Sticky` setting isn't the real problem, the problem is that the hover disappears before you even get the mouse to it.]

Comment: wow exactly what I needed! Also they dropping win7 support :(