# VSCode: How to change the delay for hover?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you hover your mouse over some code, it will attempt to tell you more about the thing you are hovered over. Sometimes it is more information about the function, or it will tell you how a symbol is defined, etc...

I like this feature, but it happens WAY too fast. I will be attempting to double click a symbol so that I can copy-paste it, and the window will popup and I end up double clicking something inside the dialog and not the code. How do I tell VSCode to wait like 1sec before showing this dialog? I couldn't find a setting for this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Look for

> Editor > Hover: Delay
>
> Controls the delay in milliseconds after which the hover is shown.

Comment: Just to clarify: where do I look for "Editor > ..."?

Comment: I know this is old, but to add to the clarification: Click on **Manage** (gear icon on the bottom left) -> **Settings** -> Type in the search bar `editor:hover` and you'll see the option mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Upon discovering this. I've set mine to 1500, and couldn't be happier.

Comment: Is there a post delay option too? For some reason when I try to point at it to copy content the popup disappears fast.

Comment: @VincentAlex Help is coming - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73938349/836330

Answer (score 5):

##### Settings JSON (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)

Simply open the settings JSON and append `"editor.hover.delay": 1500` where `1500` is the desired delay value in milliseconds. Of course, it needs to be a valid JSON file. :)

##### Settings UI (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)

Simply search for `hover delay` and configure the value of `Editor > hover delay`.