# How can I change the mouse hover delay in VS Code with Go?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, debugging

- Go version 1.18.4
- VS Code version 1.70.0

This issue annoys me and takes a lot of time. I have to wait 3 seconds every time to see the value in variables.

How can I change the mouse hover delay value in VS Code when debugging?

"Editor > Hover : Delay" doesn't work in this case (without debugging mode).

Comment: How big is your project? because sometimes, especially monorepo that is huge in size (GB) doesn't work well with VS code. By default, hover delay is 300 ms

Comment: not that big. less than 50MB. And it is same on just created project also.

Comment: could also be that there are various other plugins that you might be using - disable and check logs perhaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode: How to change the delay for hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60706971/vscode-how-to-change-the-delay-for-hover)